# Wofür steht das „es“ in „Geht’s noch?“?

Tags: idiom

Nur um das Beleidigungspotenzial zu beschränken, möchte ich gerne wissen, wofür steht das *es* in „Geht’s noch?“ Beispielsweise Wiktionary deutet daraufhin, dass die oder der Sprechende würde seinen Gesprächspartner [für verrückt halten](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geht%E2%80%99s_noch). Ist *es* ein Platzhalter? Ist *es* das Gehirn? Eine Ellipse?

Comment: Der verlinkte wiktionary-Artikel ist aber zu eng gefasst,es gibt noch eine zweite, *nicht beleidigende* Bedeutung (der Unterschied liegt einzig und allein im Tonfall). Es kann auch fürsorglich gemeint sein im Sinne von "hältst Du noch durch, oder brauchst Du eine Pause", gestellt an den, der die schwerste Last trägt, die schwächste Kondition hat oder gesundheitlich angeschlagen ist.

Comment: Meiner bescheidenen Meinung nach wäre ein Vergleich zum Reflexivpronomen *si, sich*, bzw. dem demonstrativpronomen *so* angezeigt. Leider ist mir weder eine Ausarbeitung noch eine wirklich Schlüssige Herleitung bekannt. Vergleich etwa "Mir ist so schlecht" (*I'm sick*) und Bairisch *mir* als reguläres Pronomen, und auf der anderen Seite die ganz andere Entwicklung des selbst-reflexiven Pronomens in Englisch. Die Bedeutung ist jedenfalls passiv, nicht ich gehe, sondern Übel ergeht mir (das ist er-gativ, haha): *mir wird Spei übel*.

Comment: Du müsstest mal aufklären, ob hier mit "Geht's noch?" die fürsorgliche Frage nach der Befindlichkeit eines anderen gemeint ist oder die Frage nach dem Zustandekommen einer abwegigen Handlung.

Comment: Zur eigentlichen Frage, wofür das "es" hier steht meine ich, dass es sich um das gleiche "es" handelt, wie in "Wie geht es dir?". Also ein Scheinsubjekt ("dummy subject").

Answer (score 7):

Ich halte das für eine Verkürzung von

> (Aber sonst) geht (e)s (Dir) noch (gut)?

die aufgrund des weggefallenen *dir* auch für Unannehmlichkeiten, die nicht von einer Person verursacht worden sind, verwendet werden kann. Die Bedeutungen hat olafant  ziemlich erschöpfend behandelt, Beispiele dafür findet man [hier](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Geht%27s%20noch%3F%20Geht%20es%20noch%3F&bool=relevanz&suchspalte%2525252525252525255B%2525252525252525255D) reichlich.

Insofern ist *es* dasselbe wie in *Geht es dir gut?*

Comment: Sehe es ähnlich (siehe oben).

Comment: Wenn ich beim Bergsteigen den Partner frage: "Geht's noch?", dann könntest du recht haben. Aber darum geht es in der Frage m.E. nicht.

Comment: @Olafant, ich finde, das passt auch bei der sarkastischischen Fragen nach der psychischen Gesundheit.

Answer (score 5):

Ich würde es auf eine Weglassung zurückführen: "Geht's noch (gut oder eher schlecht)? bezogen auf die psychische Gesundheit. In diesem Fall wäre "es" ein Scheinsubjekt ("dummy subject") wie in "es regnet".

Comment: Nein "es" als Pronom ohne Bezug auf etwas/jemand: "es regnet/es ist spät" etc. Das ist kein Demonstrativ, und ich wüsste nicht, was das mit dem Slavischen zu tun hat... PS. Wieso "Sie"?

Comment: Um es mit vectorys Worten zu sagen: Vergleiche geht's gut, geht's schlecht

Comment: Um es mit Hape Kerkeling zu beschreiben: Austausch im Sinne von Verkehr zwischen zwei fremden Welten (egal wie man es nimmt) funktioniert genauso wenig wie Geschlechtsverkehr: "Geh-schlecht" ;-)

Comment: *Geht's noch* fragt aber nicht danach, wie es dem Handelnden geht. Es drückt aus, dass dem Fragenden die Handlung nicht sonderlich behagt.

Comment: Das ist mir schon klar. Es war eine Hypothese über den Ursprung des Ausdrucks...

Answer (score 3):

Das "es" steht für gar nichts, nur braucht jeder deutsche Satz (außer im Passiv) ein Jemand oder ein Etwas, welches die Aktion ausführt. Also tut man ein fiktives Subjekt in den Satz, eben das Es.

Ich sehe dieses Es gleichwertig mit dem Es in "Es regnet." Also einfach von der grammatikalischen Seite, es formt den Satz entsprechend den Erfordernissen/Regeln der deutschen Satzgrammatik.

Answer (score 2):

Das Beleidigunspotential hängt von der Situation ab, in der diese Frage gestellt wird. Wenn ich beim Bergwandern meinen schnaufenden Partner fürsorglich frage:

> Geht's noch?

dann erkundige ich mich nach seiner Befindlichkeit im Sinne von

- Kannst du noch?
- Geht es dir noch gut?

Da handelt es sich dann also eher um eine Auslassung gepaart mit dem Platzhaltersubjekt *es* und da besteht auch nicht die Gefahr, dass er das als beleidigend empfinden könnte.

Frage ich aber jemanden, dessen Handlung mir unverständlich ist, (und womöglich in ärgerlichem Tonfall)

> Geht's noch?

lässt sich das umschreiben mit

- Kommst du noch klar?
- Weißt du noch, was du tust?
- Hast du noch Orientierung?
- Bist du noch bei Sinnen?
- Bist du noch bei klarem Verstand (bei Trost)?

Das *es* scheint hier erst einmal ein allgemeiner Platzhalter dafür zu sein, ob *die normalen Denk- und Handlungsroutinen* noch funktionieren. Da das aber letztlich alles auf die Frage nach der geistigen Verfassung abzielt, halte ich die Interpretation, das *es* stünde für *das Gehirn*, für alles andere als abwegig. Im Gegenteil - ich finde das eine sehr interessante Beobachtung.

Die Frage *Geht's noch?* drückt hier Unverständnis für eine Handlung aus. Alle Handlungen sind hirngesteuert. Wenn man sich in ärgerlicher Weise darüber wundert, wie es zu einer Handlung kommt, zweifelt man also letztlich daran, ob das Gehirn des Handelnden noch fehlerfrei funktioniert.

In diesem Fall kann so eine Frage ziemlich beleidigend sein. Es wäre ja durchaus möglich, dass ich die Beweggründe, die zu der Handlung geführt haben, nicht durchschaue. Besser wäre es dann vielleicht, sein Unverständnis klar auszudrücken und nachzufragen.

> Das verstehe ich nicht, was du da gerade gemacht hast. Kannst du mir das erklären?

Falls die Handlung dann immer noch nicht nachvollziehbar ist, kann vielleicht [Einsteins Sicht zur Willensfreiheit](https://www.einstein-website.de/z_biography/glaubensbekenntnis.html) über den Unmut hinweg helfen:

<sub>"Ich glaube nicht an die Freiheit des Willens. Schopenhauers Wort: 'Der Mensch kann wohl tun, was er will, aber er kann nicht wollen, was er will', begleitet mich in allen Lebenslagen und versöhnt mich mit den Handlungen der Menschen, auch wenn sie mir recht schmerzlich sind. Diese Erkenntnis von der Unfreiheit des Willens schützt mich davor, mich selbst und die Mitmenschen als handelnde und urteilende Individuen allzu ernst zu nehmen und den guten Humor zu verlieren."</sub>

Schließlich gibt es auch noch die eher scherzhafte Frage in der zweiten Bedeutung - aber mit einem Lächeln - zum Beispiel an einen Freund, der gerade irgendwie seltsam durch die Gegend tanzt. Da ist dann klar, dass das nicht beleidigend gemeint ist. Einer Person, die das nicht so zu deuten weiß (weil man sich z.B. nicht so gut kennt), würde ich auch in scherzhafter Absicht diese Frage besser nicht stellen. Da wäre mir das Beleidungspotential zu hoch.

Comment: Ich stimme zu, außer dem Bezug zum Gehirn. Das ist viel zu spezifisch. Jemand der diesen Ausdruck verwendet denkt nicht an die Funktionalität des Gehirns. In den meisten Fällen wird sogar eher der Charakter angezweifelt, oft mit dem Gefühl der Adressat ist rücksichtslos oder ignorant.

Answer (score 1):

Meines Erachtens ist die Bedeutung von *gehts noch* in

> Sag mal, gehts noch?

von [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/geht%E2%80%99s_noch) richtig gedeutet als *signalisiert einem Menschen, dass er für verrückt gehalten wird*, also gleichbedeutend mit

> Sag mal, spinnst du?

Da es sich um eine Wendung handelt, kann man die Bestandteile nicht austauschen und in diesem Fall noch nicht einmal umordnen oder in eine Aussage verwandeln; jeder solche Versuch führt dazu, daß die idiomatische Bedeutung verschwindet. Daher sehe ich keinen Grund, *es* irgendeine Art von Referentialität zuzusprechen: *es* ist ein formales Subjekt ohne Inhalt.

Die der Wendung am nächsten stehende Bedeutung von *gehen* ist meiner Ansicht nach die folgende:

> Geht es noch mit den Schmerzen? – Es geht noch.
> "Die Schmerzen sind noch zu ertragen."
>
> Momentan geht es noch mit der Hitze.
> "Die Hitze ist noch zu ertragen."

Der Bedeutungswandel zu *spinnst du?* erklärt sich möglicherweise daraus, daß es in der Regel bemitleidenswerte Menschen waren, denen solche Fragen gestellt wurden: Alte, Kranke und möglicherweise auch Verrückte.

Wie die Paraphrasen mit *ertragen* verdeutlichen, ist *es* auch hier nicht referentiell. Wenn die Präpositionalphrase *mit …* fehlt, muß das zu Ertragende aus dem Kontext erschlossen werden.

Dieser Gebrauch von *gehen* stammt wohl von älterem *angehen*:

> etw. geht (gerade noch, schon) an (= ist erträglich) [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/angehen), 5.
>
> *die schmerzen gehn noch an,* sind leidlich, mäszig; *die hitze geht diesen sommer noch an,* ist nicht allzu heftig. [DWB](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=1,339,75) 2) d)

Comment: Auch 'ne gute Hypothese, wobei ich mit der Definition von Wiki nicht so ganz einverstanden bin, denn der Ausdruck -zumindest in meiner Region- wird auch für temporäre Situationen verwendet, d.h. wenn jemand etwas Unerwartetes und  Unangebrachtes tut.